# I want to fetch {0} from loginName FormatString property

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<td align="right" width="100%">
    <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server"   FormatString="Currently logged in as: {0}" />
</td>
```

Here is my code in aspx file and i want to fetch string {0} in .cs file.How to do it?

Comment: What do you mean with "fetch"? That string is internally used with String.Format(FormatString, LoggedInUserName).

Comment: i want the username from {0} so that i can stored it in another string for further usage in C#

Comment: try `User.Identity.Name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either the [LoginName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginname.aspx) control, or accessing your current identity using `Page.User.Identity.Name`.

```
<div>You are <%: Page.User.Identity.Name %>!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the login name on any page after Login Page. ( you have first page for login, Where you have authenticated user).

In that login page you can store the fetched User Login Name in Session variable, then use that session variable then after in all other page to display name.

Hope this will help you.
thanks.

Comment: Actaully i dnt have any login page, My user name comes from windows login